# JavaScript IntelliSense for external library is not working in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am trying to use the Azure Document DB Server-Side JavaScript IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I have downloaded the `.js` file from Document DB's [GitHub site](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/tree/master/utils) into my Visual Studio JavaScript references folder:

[image]

And referenced it in my `.js` file, but I don't see any Document DB IntelliSense:

[image]

However, if I open `DocDbWrapperScript.js` in VS the IntelliSense starts working:

[image]

Have I missed some config somewhere to make the `/// <reference path="foo.js" />` syntax work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The following rules apply to a reference directive:
>
> - The reference XML comment must be declared before any script.
> - You must use XML comments syntax with three slashes. References made by using standard comments syntax (two slashes) are ignored.
> - Only one file or resource can be specified per directive.
> - Multiple references to page-based scripts are not allowed.
> - If a page reference is specified, no other type of reference directives is allowed.
> - File names use relative paths. You can use the tilde operator (~) to make application-root-relative paths.
> - **Absolute paths are ignored.**
> - Reference directives in referenced pages will not be processed—that is, reference directives are not resolved recursively for pages.
> - Only script that is referenced directly by the page is included.

Switching over to use a relative path in the `/// <reference path="..." />` fixed the IntelliSense for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, please make sure the path is correct.

You can also try to register the docdbwrapperscript.js in General section: Tools->Options->Text Editor->JavaScript->Intellisense->References, ReferenceGroup = Generic, add a path to docdbwrapperscript.js there.

Thanks!

Comment: I double checked the paths - they all look correct, but I still see the behaviour above.  I also tried adding it to the Generic reference group, but that didn't work either.  I'm not sure that's the right solution though - wouldn't that make the Doc DB intellisense available to all `.js` files?  I think it should only be available in files that opt into it using the `/// <reference path="foo.js" />` syntax.

Comment: Yes, adding to Generic section would make it available for all JS files. 
The issue could be perf-related -- JS language service may not fit in time processing the file. We can possibly provide a much simpler file, but before we go there, can you please check that simple files work in your environment? For instance, create a js file with a var, reference it by direct path and see if you get intellisense?

Comment: Ok, so I just tried a simple `.js` with one var as you suggested and I still get the same behaviour as in my original question.  I've done some more digging this afternoon, and it turns out absolute paths are not supported in the reference tags (see my answer below).  When I switched to a relative path the intellisensestarts working.